# using VBA to open webpage and pull specific line of data then place it in cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

what I am trying to do is use VBA code, or any way actually to lookup a website and pull a CPU model found by using the Id I assume. I then need it to take that CPU model and Paste it into the Corresponding Cell in excel.

here are my examples.

I need the website https://partsurfer.hpe.com/Search.aspx?SearchText= to be pulled up with the cell from S/N to be appended right after the =
it then pulls a website with the hardware information. and line 33 is the cpu model. I need that populated into the CPU cell corresponding to the Serial number.

a serial number to test with MXQ2040F21
[image: inventory list]

[image: power query table]

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried on your own? Please edit the question, include your code attempt and explain what is not working.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial of what you need to do. https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm

Comment: Will the CPU model always be contained in row 33?

Comment: I have checked about 12 different ones, and it has always been on the 33rd row.
however I know there isa  way to pull info from the span id in the HTML so I am going to look at that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that combines the cell iteration and the more robust web fetch from my prior two attempts.

```
Sub get_computer_data()
    
    ' be sure to set these two constants and a variable
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = "computers" ' name of the sheet that has the computer data
    Dim serialNumCol As Byte
    serialNumCol = 4 ' the number of the column that has the serial number
    Dim r As Long: r = 2 ' the row the computer data starts on
    
    Dim s As Worksheet
    
    Set s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName) 'process a specific sheet
    
    ' process all rows of contiguous data
    Do Until s.Cells(r, 1).Value = ""
        s.Cells(r, serialNumCol + 2).Value = get_processor(s.Cells(r, serialNumCol).Value)
        r = r + 1
    Loop


End Sub

Function get_processor(serial_number) As String
    Dim position As Long
    Dim search As String
    Dim processor As String
    Dim html As String
    Const url = "https://partsurfer.hpe.com/Search.aspx?SearchText="
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", url & serial_number, False
    xmlhttp.Send
    
    html = xmlhttp.responseText
    
    ' find the tag that idenifies the processor in the html
    search = "ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_gridCOMBOM_ctl34_lblpartdesc1"">"
    position = InStr(1, html, search) + Len(search)
    if position = 0 then
        get_processor = "not found"
    else
        processor = Split(Mid(html, position), "<")(0)
        get_processor = processor
    end iff
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below uses Excel's built-in "web query" feature to pull the as you have described.  This code brings in the value from the 33rd row of the table that comes back from the web request.  However, I'm skeptical that the CPU data will always be on the 33rd row and I don't see a way based on results from the webserver to infer what the right line is.  Hopefully, this gets you headed in the right direction.

```
Sub get_computer_data()
    
    ' be sure to set these two constants and a variable
    Dim SheetName as String
    SheetName = "computers" ' name of the sheet that has the computer data
    Dim serialNumCol as Byte
    serialNumCol = 5 ' the number of the column that has the serial number
    Dim r As Long: r = 2 ' the row the computer data starts on
    
    Dim url as String
    url = "https://partsurfer.hpe.com/Search.aspx?SearchText="
    Dim s As Worksheet ' a reference
    Dim query As Worksheet ' a variable to refer to the sheet created by the web query
    Dim cell As Range ' a range object used to find data in the query result
    
    Set s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName) 'process a specific sheet
    
    ' process all rows of contiguous data
    Do Until s.Cells(r, 1).Value = ""
        'perform a web query for the current serial number
        Set query = CreateWebQuery(url & s.Cells(r, serialNumCol).Value, xlAllTables)
        
        ' find the data on the result page
        Set cell = query.Cells.Find("Part Description", , , xlWhole)
        If cell Is Nothing Then
            s.Cells(r, serialNumCol + 2).Value = "No Data"
        Else
            s.Cells(r, serialNumCol + 2).Value = cell.Offset(33)
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop


End Sub




Function CreateWebQuery(url As String, Optional WebSelectionType As XlWebSelectionType = xlEntirePage, Optional SaveQuery As Boolean, Optional PlainText As Boolean = True, Optional SheetName As String = "webQuery") As Worksheet

  '*********************************************************************************'
  '         Builds a web-query object to retrieve information from a web server and
  '         returns a reference to a worksheet containing the data
  '
  '    Parameters:
  '
  '
  '        URL
  '          The webpage to get. Should start with "http"
  '
  '        WebSelectionType (xlEntirePage or xlAllTables)
  '          what part of the page should be brought back to Excel.
  '
  '        SaveQuery (True or False)
  '          Indicates if the query object remains in the workbook after running
  '
  '        PlainText (True or False)
  '          Indicates if the query results should be plain or include formatting
  '
  '       SheetName
  '         Indicates the name of the sheet to create or use
  '
  '*********************************************************************************'
      Dim outsheet As Worksheet
      Dim s As Worksheet
      Set s = ActiveSheet

      On Error Resume Next
      Set outsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
      If Err.Number = 0 Then
          outsheet.Cells.Clear
      Else
          Set outsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
          outsheet.Name = SheetName
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
      
      s.Activate
  
      With outsheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, Destination:=outsheet.Range("a1"))
        .Name = "WebQuery"
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .WebSelectionType = WebSelectionType
        .PreserveFormatting = PlainText
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        If Not SaveQuery Then .Delete
    End With
    
    Set CreateWebQuery = outsheet
    
End Function
```

Comment: I have looked up 12 different serial numbers and the all have the CPU in the 33rd line... however can we use VBA to pull the Span ID? the cpu will always be <span id="ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_gridCOMBOM_ctl34_lblpartdesc1"?

Comment: unfortunately, the web query tool only exposes the text visible on the page, it would take other techniques to get at the underlying tags.  I'll write another answer showing that approach.

Comment: also I get "Constant Expression Required" when trying to run it. is this doe to trying to Dim against variable size? would I have to ReDim r since we are increasing it?

Comment: Be sure that you are not trying to run any code on the "Const" statements.  you can only use numeric and string literals there

Comment: I dont think I am. still new to VBA (thanks for all the help) if there is anything I can let me know. 
I have a module with the Sub in it.. then another module with the function. (correct?)

Comment: Your configuration should be fine.  You certainly can have both in the same module.  What line is the error happening on?  What version of Excel, and what OS are you using?  Try the other code (you can put it all in the same module with the others).  Just run the "test" sub procedure and let me know if it prints the processor in the immediate windows (you may need to press "ctrl+g" to open the immediate window)

Comment: ok, the Test Sub Procedure does show the Processor in the immediate window.

it does not give me a line that the error is happening with, it just highlights "Sub get_computer_data()" 

I have windows 10 with Excel for 365

Comment: This seems that it must be a problem with the "const" statements.  I've changed them to "Dim" so try again.

Comment: AH HA! ok so the issue now lies with the Column, it doesnt error but fills column "G" with "No Data" if I leave it as "serialNumCol = 5"

if I change that to "D" because thats the column where the serial numbers live, I get an error with line "set Query"
the Error is Runtime error '1004':
application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: it's a column number.  use 4 instead of "D"

Comment: I hope this has got you going.  If these have been helpful, you should choose one to mark as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to get get the data you are after using a more direct method than the web query method in my other answer.  This function takes a serial number and returns the processor.

```
Sub test()
   Debug.Print get_processor("MXQ2040F21")
End Sub

Function get_processor(serial_number) As String
    Dim position As Long
    Dim search As String
    Dim processor As String
    Dim html As String
    Const url = "https://partsurfer.hpe.com/Search.aspx?SearchText="
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", url & serial_number, False
    xmlhttp.Send
    
    html = xmlhttp.responseText
    
    ' find the tag that idenifies the processor in the html
    search = "ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_gridCOMBOM_ctl34_lblpartdesc1"">"
    position = InStr(1, html, search) + Len(search)
    processor = Split(Mid(html, position), "<")(0)
    get_processor = processor
    
End Function
```